# Where should my npm modules be installed on Mac OS X?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

I was attempting to upgrade `phonegap` via `npm` when I started running into trouble. Long story short, there are two `node_modules` directories on my computer.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules
```

When I run `npm upgrade -g phonegap`, it appears that `npm` updates the copy of the package that resides in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. However, if I `which phonegap` I find that the symlink points to the older installation at `/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules`.

Also, when I attempt to install a stand alone package such as `express`, the files are installed in the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` directory, <strike>but no symlink to the executable is created in anywhere in my `$PATH`.</strike>

Two questions:

- Which is the proper directory for node modules on Mac OS X?
- <strike>How can I configure `npm` to link executables in my `$PATH` when it installs software?</strike>

Bonus points: Does the method of installing `node` affect the configuration? There are a [lot of options](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814).

---

**EDIT**: I figured out that symlinks were being created in my `/usr/local/bin`, but my `.bash_profile` was setup with `/usr/local/share/npm/bin` ahead of `/usr/local/bin` in my `$PATH`. I vaguely remember adding that path to my profile at some point, but I'm not sure why.

So the question now becomes: how did I end up with two different `node_modules` directories on my computer and why would I want to have my `node_modules` in the `share/npm/lib` subdirectory instead of right in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: use `npm root -g` to find the path to global packages root

Answer (score 145, accepted):

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules` is the correct directory for globally installed node modules.

`/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules` makes no sense to me. One issue here is that you're confused because there are two directories called **node_modules**:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules`
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules`

The latter seems to be node modules that came with Node, e.g., `lodash`, when the former is Node modules that I installed using `npm`.

Comment: What is the difference between this two nodes? For OS X users is recommended when installing to use the one from node. Should it be better to move to a proper installation of npm?

Comment: Installed npm2 from macports, your paths are absent in those locations, also as absent in /opt/local/share..

Answer (score 156):

```
npm root -g
```

to check the npm_modules global location

Comment: The nicest and easiest way to find the global path of node_modules.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Concise and accurate and works under all circumstances i.e. nvm or without nvm + multiple node versions installed.

Answer (score 106):

Second [Thomas David Kehoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5153354/thomas-david-kehoe), with the following caveat --

If you are using node version manager (nvm), your global node modules will be stored under whatever version of node you are using at the time you saved the module.

So `~/.nvm/versions/node/{version}/lib/node_modules/`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

Find the current path for current active `npm` installation:

`npm root -g`

OR try one of these popular defaults:

Linux:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules`

MacOS (installed through brew):

`/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules`

Linux (probably macos also) when installed with nvm:

`~/.nvm/versions/node/{version}/lib/node_modules/`

Windows (bonus )

`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\`

Answer (score 15):

If you want to know the location of you NPM packages, you should:

```
which npm // locate a program file in the user's path SEE man which
// OUTPUT SAMPLE
/usr/local/bin/npm
la /usr/local/bin/npm // la: aliased to ls -lAh SEE which la THEN man ls
lrwxr-xr-x  1 t04435  admin    46B 18 Sep 10:37 /usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

So given that npm is a NODE package itself, it is installed in the same location as other packages(**EUREKA**). So to confirm you should cd into node_modules and list the directory.

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
ls
#SAMPLE OUTPUT
@angular npm .... all global npm packages installed
```

## OR

```
npm root -g
```

As per @anthonygore 's comment

Comment: Easier: npm root -g

Comment: for me, `npm root -g` and `which npm` didn't give the same results. I wanted to uninstall `expo-cli` and I succeeded by removing `expo` and `expo-cli` directories from `/usr/local/bin/npm`. Thank You @T04435 !

Answer (score 1):

use this command:
`npm -t` -> to find the path to your global npm package.

if you are using nvm (node version manager package). Then your path may
look something like this `/Users/yourName/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.3/lib/node_modules/npm`

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked for me and I am on Mac OS (Catalina currently).  What I wanted was a portable experience like Go gives me, where I can specify where I want global modules/packages to be installed.  Particularly, I wanted the packages to be installed in my user/home directory.

First, I ran this to set the global prefix for NPM:

```
npm -g set prefix $HOME/.npm-global
```

Then, I added the bin to my PATH (inside `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=$HOME/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Now, when I install a global package like the Angular CLI, I can be sure I'm referencing the proper location with this command:

```
which ng
```

Or via NPM:

```
npm -g list
```

Hope it helps.