# eslint-config-google doesn't detect globally installed eslint

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, eslint, linter, eslintrc

Whenever I try to install **eslint-config-google** *globally* via

`npm install -g eslint-config-google`

I get

```
npm WARN eslint-config-google@0.9.1 requires a peer of eslint@>=4.1.1 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

But when I do `eslint --v` just to reconfirm, I get `v4.16.0`.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

---

**Dependant question**: Also, I have a global default `.eslintrc` file in my `~`(home) folder which I point to from the `linter - eslint` package in Atom. When I save any .js file on Atom, I get

`Cannot find module 'eslint-config-google' Referenced from: /Users/aakashverma/.eslintrc.js`

This is my `.eslintrc.js` file in `~`:

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "google"],
  "rules": {
    "indent": [
      "error",
      4
    ],
    "linebreak-style": [
      "error",
      "unix"
    ],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single"
    ],
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ],
    // allow console and debugger in development
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0,
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 2 : 0,
  }
}
```

[This kind of talks about it.](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/603)

Comment: What is your Atom setting for the eslint executable?  You might try pointing it directly to your module folder eg ~/node_modules/eslint/bin

Comment: @Papasmile My .eslintrc path is set to `~/.eslintrc.js` where my file actually is. There's no problem in reading or accessing that file by any of the projects. It's just that it is not able to detect `eslint-config-google`.

Comment: ah, got ya.  I think atom does not use global plugins, see https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/110

Comment: @Papasmile It did, man. Please review my answer.

Comment: You have 'use global' turned off, right?  So it's technically using a 'local' plugin, but it seems too have had a hard time finding it for some reason... cool that adding it $PATH did the trick.

Comment: I don't have a copy of `.eslintrc` in local so it must be the global file that it is referencing using the `.eslintrc Path`. Right?

Comment: Just saying if 'use global' is turned off it thinks you have a local package installed and you've added your globally installed packages to your runtime using $PATH so it looks like a local file.... anyway all that is a bit silly so +1 for posting your experience to https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/603 that's probably a good place to figure out a root cause :)

Comment: @Papasmile Got it. There's only so much you can ever contribute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I am not sure if this was a cache problem or something but I don't think it was because I kept restarting Atom and zsh but here's how it worked:

In Atom, I changed `.eslintrc Path` to `~/.eslintrc.js` and `Use global ESlint installation` to `checked.

And this is my `.eslintrc` in the home folder as pointed to in Atom

[image]

And lastly, to make it work with `Use global ESlint installation` turned on, I included both `eslint-config-google` and `eslint` in my `$PATH` variable this way

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/aakashverma/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint/
/Users/aakashverma/.nvm/versions/node/v9.4.0/lib/node_modules/eslint-config-google/
```

Refer to the answer by @ginna [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045946/where-should-my-npm-modules-be-installed-on-mac-os-x) and my comment [here](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/603) .

Comment: There's one more untested way [here](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-eslint/issues/257) if you refer to @darkred's comment.