# How to get appium-chromedriver version

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, appium

I installed appium-chromedriver via mpm  using below command , may I know how to get the installed version of it ?

```
npm install -g appium-chromedriver
```

appium-chromedriver [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-chromedriver)

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` in macos [ref stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638528/5875610)
And `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm` in Windows. Check the package.json in both directories for npm version. Also this could easily be found out with Google.

Comment: Also `npm show [package-name] version`

Comment: Thank s a lot, The second comment was helpful using that I was able to get the path  npm show appium-chromedriver version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the guidance of Kevin's  comment npm show node-package-name version , I was able to derive the version.

```
 npm show appium-chromedriver version
```

[image]