# NPM Error : Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/npm'

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions

I created an index.js, index.html and package.json file and I wanted to add express. When I write 'npm install express' in the terminal, I'm getting the error below. So far, I tried 'sudo npm install -g express', deleting node and npm completely and re-install. I also went through other questions over here but none of them worked out for me. Whatever I write with npm I get the same error. (I'm using macOS)

Do you have any suggestions?

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/npm'

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined

    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97:27)

    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:78:20

    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:225:22)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:263:24

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:81:7

    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:80:13

    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)

    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:171:20)

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97

  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true

                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined

    at exit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:97:27)

    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:216:3)

    at process.emit (events.js:223:5)

    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:150:25)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error means that you have no permission to install anything with npm at the path `/npm`.
To verify this run `npm root -g`. This should return `/npm`.

Note that `/npm` ist not the default installation path on MacOS (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638528/1754076).

Checkout your npm configuration file and change the default installation path to something where you do have write access. You can also use npm itself to [change the default installation path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28205851/1754076).

Answer (score 1):

mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc.old

npm prefix -g

this might work

Answer (score 1):

In my case it turned out to be a problem with the `cache` entry in the `~/.npmrc` file.  Apparently one of the sub-projects I have worked on required the line:

`cache=/build/package_cache/npm`

But when run in another sub-project it seems to have caused npm to not be able to create the `/build` directory.

Commenting out that line worked around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had error `EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/.npm'` while I was trying  to install packages.

Then I used  `npm config list --json` and found only thing used this path is `"cache": "/.npm"`.

So I changed cache by `npm config set cache '/tmp'`, then installation worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when trying to write to a file because of a leading slash that I had in front of the filename so using the following line causes the issue :

```
fs.writeFileSync("/output.txt", JSON.stringify(data), "utf8");
```

While the issue is gone with the below one (after removing the leading slash):

```
fs.writeFileSync("output.txt", JSON.stringify(data), "utf8");
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I deleted `~/.local/lib`, then re-ran the `npm install -g` command. No more error.