# error Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/user'

Tags: npm-install

I am trying to install NPM Install Sharp.

Error

```
EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/user'
```

Comment: Probably [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020217/npm-error-error-erofs-read-only-file-system-mkdir-npm) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc.old

npm prefix -g

This might fix your issues