# Error: EROFS: read-only file system on ionic installation

Tags: ionic-framework, npm

I am trying to create an ionic project and running the command:

`sudo ionic start helloworld blank`

However when I do the terminal outputs

`Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/helloworld'`

Then the process just hangs. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling npm and ionic, but this problem has not resolved.

Comment: Probably duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020217/npm-error-error-erofs-read-only-file-system-mkdir-npm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM Error : Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/npm'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60020217/npm-error-error-erofs-read-only-file-system-mkdir-npm)