# I cannot deploy my website even though firebase is installed

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I am trying to download firebase, but even after I run:

```sh
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I get:

> zsh: command not found: firebase

when trying: `firebase -v`

could it have something to do with:

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.3: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

Comment: You can ignore those deprecation warnings (they're not your problem). What was the output from running `npm install -g firebase-tools`? Also, which version of Node are you using and what OS (Windows, Mac, etc)?

Comment: @Phil Thanks. I'm on Mac (m1). Node version is v19.3.0. Only thing outputted by the install statement is: changed 613 packages in 6s

34 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details. Then when I put in npm fund is just gives me my username back

Comment: If it installed correctly, it's probably just that your `PATH` doesn't include npm global installs. See [Where should my npm modules be installed on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25045946/283366). Also check out the [automatic install script](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script) which doesn't use NPM